# Visual Studio Code command "yarn studio" does not work - "The system cannot find the file specified" error

Tags: angular, android-studio, visual-studio-code, yarnpkg

I'm working on hybrid project of Angular with Android, my environment is Visual Studio Code. I'm trying to open this project in Android Studio with command "yarn studio", but it does not work. Does anyone have any suggestions? (P.S. commands "yarn" and "yarn build" work properly)

Error body in node terminal:

yarn run v1.22.19
$ export $(xargs <.env) && npx cap sync android && npx cap open android
The system cannot find the file specified.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Comment: per the docs: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v2/basics/building-your-app wouldn't it be npx? I assume this is an ionic/capacitor app. Also is android studio installed? as i am quite confident that "yarn studio" wouldn't be a standard yarn command

Comment: ok, from your reference command "npx cap open android" works just fine! thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this documentation](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v2/basics/building-your-app), use:

```
npx cap copy android
npx cap open android
```